# How to not convert or escape " // " characters in an HTTP response

Tags: python, json, http, response, html-escape-characters

I am using the twitter API, and when I make a request to the api website, something like 
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?user_id=myUserId&count=1

I get the correct response back, JSON data, except all of the `//` characters are escaped and are shown as `\/\/`

This is true for the command line, using `curl` and when i type that url directly into the browser.

If it makes any difference, I am ultimately going to be calling a function and navigating to that URL so I need it to be the unescaped.

Furthermore, I will be accessing that URL with Python, so if there is a Python method that is good, but ideally I would just get the response back  unchanged.

Comment: Why? They decode back into "/".

Comment: I am using this in an application (i.e. not a web browser) that can download image files found within the links of that post. 
The entire string is going to be passed in as the link, and the escaping characters will not be correct.

Comment: Have you considered using a downloader that understands JSON?

Comment: I believe that fixed the issue. I did not have enough faith in Python. Never again. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [JSON standard](http://www.json.org/) allows (though not requires) `/` to be escaped. If you use any standard-compliant JSON parser (i.e. pretty much any JSON parser), it will do the unescaping for you.

Comment: Excellent. So, what you are saying is that, when Python parses this, it will unescape the characters and leave me with the correct URL string? 
Will also take care of the & [or] \u0026 issue?

Comment: I don't know waht you mean by "the & [or] \u0026 issue". `\u0026` is a valid JSON unicode escape, so that's unescaped for you as well. There should be no issue with `&` as it requires/allows neither escaping nor unescaping. Why don't you just try it and see?